# How to create folders and subfolders using PHP where user can give his own NAME and number of folders to be created

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to create folders and subfolders  using PHP where user can give his own NAME for the folders and subfolders and number of folders that has to be created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$pathToDirCreationTopDir = '/var/www/path/to';
$mainDir = $_GET['mainDir'];
$subDirs = $_GET['subDirs'];

if (!mkdir($pathToDirCreationTopDir . '/' . $mainDir)) {
    echo 'Main dir creation failed!';
    exit;
}
$pathToDirCreationTopDir = $pathToDirCreationTopDir . '/' . $mainDir;

foreach ($subDirs as $subDirName) {
    if (!mkdir($pathToDirCreationTopDir . '/' . $subDirName)) {
        echo 'Sub dir creation failed!';
        exit;
    }
}
```

If you work on Windows you need to replace the slashes (/) with backslashes ()

Comment: ya i gone through it Ofir... just need some tip how to create a architecture kind of folders and sub folders as given by the user...

Comment: How do you get the architecture from the user?

Comment: like the user needs one main folder and 2 subfolders

Comment: but the user also need to specify the name of these folders?

Comment: thats when he is going to create he has to specify the name.. thats what my question is???

Comment: You need to be more clear on how you get the data from the user. Do you get it in multi-dimensional array? or it is just a plain array? if so how you know the directories hierarchy?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3356/discussion-between-ofir-and-user876200)